# Pandas check if dataframe column contains value from list (different lengths)

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame `df1`:

```
  A
0 E2
1 27
2 99
3 NaN
4 20
5 14
```

And the following list:

```
list1 = [14, 61, 27, 82, 79, 75, 44, 10, 'E2','E9']
```

I want to add/append a new column called 'B' to `df1` that checks whether the values in column 'A' are in `list1` by returning a boolean.

Ultimately, I would want the following output in `df1`:

```
  A   B
0 E2  True
1 27  True
2 99  False
3 NaN False
4 20  False
5 14  True
```

Most of the questions I have seen regarding this have been when the length of the DataFrame column has been the same as the length of the list.

Does anyone know how to do this when the lengths are different like in this case?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), only necessary match numeric with numbers types for correct working:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].isin(list1)
```

If numeric are stored like strings e.g. `'27'` convert first values to numeric by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert strings to `NaN`, so then replace them by original values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
print (df)
     A
0   E2
1   27
2   99
3  NaN
4   20
5   14

print (df['A'].apply(type))
0      <class 'str'>
1      <class 'str'>
2      <class 'str'>
3    <class 'float'>
4      <class 'str'>
5      <class 'str'>
Name: A, dtype: object

list1 = [14, 61, 27, 82, 79, 75, 44, 10, 'E2','E9']

df['B'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce').fillna(df['A']).isin(list1)
print (df)
     A      B
0   E2   True
1   27   True
2   99  False
3  NaN  False
4   20  False
5   14   True
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it with np.where

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['E2',27,99,np.nan,20,14]})
list1 = [14, 61, 27, 82, 79, 75, 44, 10, 'E2','E9']

_condition = df1.A.isin(list1)
df1['B'] = np.where(_condition,True,False)
df1
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, so `_condition` return `True` and `False` and then convert `True` to `True` and `False` to `False` in `np.where` ? What is reason?

Comment: When I post on OS, I try to make a comprehensive code for a lambda reader, because the goal is to understand the logical of a code, of a func, etc... Here, for example, to explain that you use np.where with a condition, and that you can then affect what you want in *arg. This won't be constructive ti just show that I can solve it in one shot in that question...

Comment: I was only curious what is reason. So if use `np.where` + `isin` is is more understable like only `isin` ? I like `np.where` and use it many times, but here in my opinion is not necessary.

Comment: You are surely right. And I don't know what I would have done in a real case. But I had good vibes with that for now. :)